# Slow rendering of an *ngFor list view in Angular 2 - Utilize webworkers?

Tags: angular

I have a straight-forward list view where a single item has a lot of visual elements (imagine Quora question, but double).

It is rendered using *ngFor.

However, analyzing the rendering process in google dev tools timeline, altho I'm using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in all components there is a ton of vDom work needed to construct the initial HTML.

Here is how my timeline looks like:

[image]

zoomed:

[image]

Note that while these instructions are being played out by the browser, the ui is locked. One second on desktop, three seconds on mobile device.

I've read a couple of times about how angular was going to abstract the vdom construction in a web-worker, but I have still not found a proper guide of how to implement that.

Any pointers? Example?

Comment: Is this with prodMode and offline template compiler applied?

Comment: prod: yes, AOT compiler: no

Comment: AoT shoildn't have much influence anyeay, it just improves initial load.

Comment: How many items are rendered?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20   I had to : )

Comment: :p I didn't know if this is the full protocol or just a part of the whole. Are the items complex components? What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome stable for testing. The html of a single component is 500 lines, plus add subcomponents to it, but i also did this test with an empty html just to confirm that there is a separate `append` instruction for every item. I'll retry it now just to confirm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there actually is a separate `append` for any item. I was wondering if `*ngFor` is the right tool for the use case (so far I haven't seen arguments against it for this case). I'd suggest creating a feature request.

Comment: Yeah.. there is `append` for every item. And it wouldn't have been problematic if at least each component was rendered in a single pass.

Comment: How much slower 20 `appendChild` calls are vs a single call? Have you measured that? Are you **sure** this is the place you should be optimising first?

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn it's 20 calls if the iterated component's html is empty. Otherwise it's 20 trillion gazillion bombillion calls. Check this out: http://i.imgur.com/xi1fjtk.png and it's like a fractal, the more you zoom, the more come out xD

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how do you suggest i frame the feature request? I don't wanna say "rewrite vdom pls" :}

Comment: Optimization for DOM changes. You should provide a Plunker that demonstrates your problem. If they need more information, they'll ask for it.

Comment: Fellas, especially @GünterZöchbauer, I'm sorry. After further exploring, I figured that the premise of my question is all wrong. Those `appendChild` calls that we see in the timeline are actually vDom calls. And after they are all done and the HTML is being constructed, there is a single `insertBefore` call which pushes the HTML into the DOM in a single pass, which including layout, takes about 20ms. So to my surprise, the actual html construction which happens all in js, is what actually takes 3 seconds to finish.

Comment: Considering all this, I'm gonna rephrase the question in the closest direction, which would be in the terms of how to hand all this work to a webworker.

Comment: Here is an demo based on WebWorkers https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2b20db6c5acd60721e8a5dae2b50cdb1292f8db1/modules/playground/src/web_workers/todo. But WebWorkers are more about improving speed of the subsequent UI updates, while AoT compiler helps more, as was said above, with the initial rendering.

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful to set up a demo in codepen or jsFiddle where people can see the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to inefficient use of NgModules. Even if you're not using AOT, you have to be aware of what is being prepped by the compiler, e.g., entryComponents